# Error: celsius cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, variables, methods

Getting error with the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FahrenheitToCelsius{


 public static void main(String[]args){
    convertFToC();
 }

  /*gets input representing fahrenheit and displays celsius equivalent*/
  public static void convertFToC(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Fahrenheit temperature");
    double fahrenheit = scan.nextInt();            
    System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " +
      fMethod(celsius) + " degrees Celsius");
  }


  /* calculates and returns the celsius equivalent */
  public static double toCelsius(double fahr){
    int BASE = 32;
    double CONVERSION_FACTOR = 9.0/ 5.0;
    double celsius = ((fahr-BASE)/(CONVERSION_FACTOR));
    return celsius;
  }
}
```

I get the following:

```
Error: celsius cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I need to use `fMethod` to call the `toCelsius` in the `System.out.println` however i keep getting this error.

Comment: _celsius cannot be resolved to a variable_ where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + fMethod(celsius) + " degrees Celsius"); //Step 4
```

should probably read

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + toCelsius(fahrenheit) + " degrees Celsius"); //Step 4
```

Comment: @Ron_ish - as much as I appreciate the accept, I think it's rightfully Jon's - he got the same answer, and got it first (not that he actually needs the rep!)

Answer (score 7):

You haven't shown `fMethod` at all, but it looks like you just want:

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + toCelsius(fahrenheit)
                   + " degrees Celsius");
```

You can't use `celsius` in `main` because it's a local variable in the `toCelsius` method. Instead, you need to *call* that method and use the return value.

Comment: @Bohemian: I'll second that. Jon Skeet - fastest fingers in the interwebs.

Answer (score 4):

You call `fMethod` which doesn't exist and pass the value of `celsius` when I think you meant `fahrenheit`.

The variable `celsius` is local to `toCelsius()` and is therefore not resolvable inside `convertFToC()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *call* your `toCelsius(double fahr)` method, like this:

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + toCelsius(fahrenheit) + " degrees Celsius"); // Step 4
```

Answer (score 3):

in the method `convertFToC()`

You get the `fahrenheit` from the user and call `fMethod(celsius)`
You were supposed to call `fMethod(`**`farenheit`**)

***More important:***

If you read the compiler error message, you get not just the error, but the file name and the line number. If you go to the line number, you see a `celcius` variable out of nowhere.

This is easy. I know asking on SO is easier, but you will never learn to read error messages and solve problems this way.

Learn to read and understand error messages. They are there for a reason.

Comment: [line: 16]
Error: The method fMethod(double) is undefined for the type FahrenheitToCelsius

Answer (score 2):

On a line marked **step4** you have an undeclared variable named `celsius`. Should be `fahrenheit` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

You are using celsius here:

```
System.out.println(fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + fMethod(celsius) + " degrees Celsius");
```

However, you did declare celsius only in `toCelsius` and that's out of scope.